# LUKS LVM as external usb volume on new computer

Tags: partitioning, encryption, lvm, luks

I'm trying to read my old encrypted hard disk (should be an entire raw LVM partition ) from a new computer.

I've detached from previous case and put the hd on a USB reader.

After entering the right keyword I get:

```
Error mounting /dev/dm-3 at /media/XXXX/multidata: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/dm-3" "/media/XXXX/multidata"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/luks-a78ea70e-7a04-4a43-bc85-f85913759553,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

and `dmesg | tail` says

```
[ 5155.229650] EXT4-fs (dm-3): bad geometry: block count 488378126 exceeds size of device (488378125 blocks)
```

`sudo lsblk` says:

```
sudo lsblk
NAME                                                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                    8:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                                 8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                                                 8:2    0   244M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                                                 8:3    0 476,2G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt (dm-0)                                252:0    0 476,2G  0 crypt 
    ├─mint--vg-root (dm-1)                           252:1    0 468,3G  0 lvm   /
    └─mint--vg-swap_1 (dm-2)                         252:2    0   7,9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb                                                    8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk  
└─sdb1                                                 8:17   0   1,8T  0 part  
  └─luks-a78e170e-7a04-4a43-bc85-f85913759553 (dm-3) 252:3    0   1,8T  0 crypt
```

`sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/luks-a78ea70e-7a04-4a43-bc85-f85913759553`

```
tune2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem volume name:   multidata
Last mounted on:          /media/XXXX/multidata
Filesystem UUID:          e6e63e8c-4b33-4f7f-8ccf-38bc91d7e771
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              122101760
Block count:              488378126
Reserved block count:     24418906
Free blocks:              239441082
Free inodes:              121146669
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      907
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue Jun 11 17:51:45 2013
Last mount time:          Tue Mar 14 09:17:58 2017
Last write time:          Tue Mar 14 16:21:29 2017
Mount count:              493
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Jun 11 17:51:45 2013
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          1289 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      58a0d9bc-ec39-4af4-8a79-59d386a867ba
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

So seems that the disk is fine but I'm still unable to read it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 -y /dev/sdb1` try this out, this tries to fix bad super block or bad sectors from ext 4 partition.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh: Good idea but `/dev/sdb1` is an encrypted partition, so `e2fsck` won't work that way.

Comment: Could you please verify the file system integrity with `e2fsck -vp /dev/mapper/luks-a78ea70e-7a04-4a43-bc85-f85913759553`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster it doesn't! I didn't know that, I've never had encrypted partition. could that command hurt his file system? i'd not wanna be responsible for spreading wrong infomation

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh: `e2fsck` will fail and and do nothing if it doesn't detect a supported file system (which it won't on encrypted media).

Comment: @DavidFoerster that's a relief

Comment: sudo e2fsck -vp /dev/mapper/luks-a78ea70e-7a04-4a43-bc85-f85913759553 
multidata: The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 488378126 blocks
The physical size of the device is 488378125 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!


multidata: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
 (i.e., without -a or -p options)

I'm proceeding with e2fsck

Comment: after e2fsck still can't mount it

dmesg | tail always says: [15664.991129] EXT4-fs (dm-3): bad geometry: block count 488378126 exceeds size of device (488378125 blocks)

Comment: nothing works. at the end i solved doing so:

sudo resize2fs -f /dev/dm-3
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/dm-3 to 488378125 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/dm-3 is now 488378125 blocks long.

 $ sudo mount -t "ext4" -o ro /dev/dm-3 /home/XXXX/multidata/

Thank you all anyway for suggestions!